# How to Remove Ubuntu 17.10 touchpad acceleration

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 17.10

I've installed ubuntu 17.10.  There is touchpad acceleration and I want to remove it.  How can I do this?  Things I've tried:

1. Using Gnome tweak tools but it does not have an option for touchpad acceleration, only mouse acceleration.
2. Using xset m 00.

Neither of the above methods worked.  Is there a way to change this?  It bothers me every time I try to move my mouse a small distance.

Comment: Have you tries touchpad settings?

Comment: Yes, I tried the touchpad settings.  There is no option for acceleration there, just speed.